# Flutter how to build a reactive 3d model

Tags: android, flutter, dart, 3d, model-viewer

I'm currently working on developing an app that utilizes nerf models to guide users to specific locations within a room. My goal is to render a 3D arrow on top of the camera, similar to what's commonly seen in video games, to provide users with directional guidance.

However, I'm encountering an issue with the model rendering using [model_viewer_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/model_viewer_plus). While my text widget updates as expected, the 3D model remains stationary.

```
class _NavigateToLocationScreenState extends State<NavigateToLocationScreen> {
  int theta = 100;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned.fill(
              child: Center(
                child: ModelViewer(
                  src: 'assets/3d_models/direction_arrow.glb',
                  alt: 'A 3D model of an astronaut',
                  ar: false,
                  autoRotate: false,
                  cameraControls: false,
                  autoPlay: false,
                  disablePan:true,
                  disableTap: true,
                  disableZoom: true,
                  fieldOfView: "${theta}deg",
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 20,
              left: 20,
              right: 20,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Slider(
                    value: theta.toDouble(),
                    min: 0,
                    max: 360,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        theta = value.toInt();
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  Text('Radius: $theta'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The initial rendering of the model changes if I change the initial specified parameters. However, subsequent re-renders fail to update the model's position or orientation.

Do you have any suggestions on how to achieve proper re-rendering of the model? I'm open to using JavaScript if necessary.

I've attempted adjusting parameters such as cameraOrbit, cameraTarget, and fieldOfView, but unfortunately, the model remains stuck in place.

I expected that I can change the orientation, position, and scale of the model programmatically.

Comment: There is an open [bug report about setState not updating the model viewer](https://github.com/omchiii/model_viewer_plus.dart/issues/99)  . IMO it seems the model viewer plugin is simplified for its one use: "viewing models". I'd probably use something less restricted, like [three_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/three_dart)